Wrapper classes is not working in my Eclipse, what am I missing?

I am trying to learn Java, and I'm in the wrapper classes topic. I am trying to use Boolean, Character, Integer and Double wrapper classes and assign value to them treating them as primitive data types. The tutorial I am watching is not having this error, but I did.
Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to Boolean
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Integer
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to Double

    at MyPackage.Main.main(Main.java:19)

Here is the code:
package MyPackage;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //wrapper class = provides a way to use primitive data types
        //as reference data types reference data types.
        //Reference data types contains useful methods can be used with
        //collection (ex. ArrayList)
        
        //primitive         wrapper
        //---------         --------
        //boolean           Boolean
        //char              Character
        //int               Integer
        //double            Double
        
        Boolean a = true;
        Character b = '@';
        Integer c = 123;
        Double d = 3.14;
        
    }
}

How can I use this wrapper classes? Do I need to import something? If so, how?
This is the Java version I have:
java 22.0.1 2024-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22.0.1+8-16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0.1+8-16, mixed mode, sharing)


What version of Java are you using? Because I suspect you have selected a truly ancient version predating autoboxing.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.  Show us the complete class that you are trying to compile.

Why did you select CDC-1.0? The Connected Device Configuration (CDC) Java runtime environment is an implementation of Java technology for connected devices. These include mobile devices like PDAs and smartphones as well as attached devices like set-top boxes, printers and kiosks. It hasn't been updated since 2005. When they say smartphones, they don't mean what you think they mean.

Your environment seems to be a mess of Java versions. The image shows two JREs for your project: CDC-1.0 and JavaSE 17. Then in your question you say you have JavaSE 22. None of those are the same.

I remove CDC-1.0, thank you for letting me know. I still has the same error though.

@Slaw how can i add my latest SDK version? I tried to create a new project but I did not see the JAVA SE - 22. I checked my my java version in CMD and it says that I have the 22.0.1

Your release of Eclipse must not contain support Java-SE 22. Does the error remain after a Clean and rebuild from the Project menu? If you open the Properties dialog for the project, what does the Java Compiler page look like? Is it set to a compliance level where this kind of conversion is allowed?

Hi nitind, compliance level solve the issue, I change the compliance level from 1.3 to 1.7. Thank you so much!

@HunMundin Java 1.7 is from 2011. You have picked another version of Java that is long in the tooth. Java 8 (or 1.8) as it was versioned back then, added lambdas. And is still 10 years old.

"how can i add my latest SDK version?" -- Make sure your version of Eclipse supports Java 22. If you have the most recent version, then I'm not sure what the problem is; I'm not that familiar with Eclipse. "I change the compliance level from 1.3 to 1.7" -- That is still a pretty old version. Your image indicates you've configured your project to use Java 17, so you should set your compliance level to 17, not 1.7.

The last Java version for which long-term support is provided is Java 21. Java 22 will become obsolete with the release of Java 23 in September 2024, years before Java 21 will become deprecated. Java 22 has been released after Eclipse 2024-03. You can install Java 22 Support for Eclipse 2024-03 (4.31) via the Eclipse Marketplace. As a beginner you better install Eclipse with an embedded Java and use this in your projects instead of using a Java installed on your system.
